# How to convert JSON within JSON into Array?

Tags: arrays, json

```
{
    "highestEducationQualification": "graduate",
    "company": "ABB LIMITED",
    "sbiDesignation": "ASSISTANT DIRECTOR",
    "availedSbiCard": "yes",
    "sbiAppliedPastSixMonths": "no",
    "availedCC": "yes",
    "sbiAssociateBanks": "no",
    "userAccountNumber": "9876545678",
    "residenceAddress": "{"doorNo":"12","addressLine1":"dfffsfsf","addressLine2":"wrwrw","pincode":"600017","city":"Chennai","state":"Tamil Nadu"}",
    "officeAddress": "{"doorNo":"2323","addressLine1":"sdsdsdsd","addressLine2":"sdfds","pincode":"600017","city":"Chennai","state":"Tamil Nadu"}"
}
```

Comment: use `json_decode();`

Comment: Tried with json_decode(). Since it is not in a proper json format. It returns empty.

Comment: tried `json_decode($value, true);`?

Comment: which language are we talking about? JavaScript?  PHP? Anyway your example is invalid JSON, so nothing can parse it

Comment: your json in invalid. please check

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
 $test = '{"highestEducationQualification": "graduate","company": "ABB LIMITED","sbiDesignation": "ASSISTANT DIRECTOR","availedSbiCard":"yes","sbiAppliedPastSixMonths":"no","availedCC":"yes","sbiAssociateBanks":"no","userAccountNumber":"9876545678","residenceAddress":{"doorNo":"12","addressLine1":"dfffsfsf","addressLine2":"wrwrw","pincode":"600017","city":"Chennai","state":"Tamil Nadu"},"officeAddress":{"doorNo":"2323","addressLine1":"sdsdsdsd","addressLine2":"sdfds","pincode":"600017","city":"Chennai","state":"Tamil Nadu"}}';  

print_r(json_decode($test, true));
?>
```

working fiddle

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bge6-qcn4

Comment: This is fine but when trying to decode the json key residenceAddress. It throws error.

Comment: your json shoulb like above

Answer (score -1):

It's not completely json format. you should convert that before use ( use any `str_replace()` functions in you language ) :

1. Convert any `"{"` to `{"`
2. convert any `"}"` to `"}`

You have mistakes in arrays.

**Wrong**

```
"residenceAddress": "{"doorNo":" .....
```

**Correct**

```
"residenceAddress": {"doorNo":" .....
```

Now you can use `json_decode()`.